# matplotlib Qt figure window crashes

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I'm running the example code from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/animation_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-animation-demo-py) (I added the `%matplotlib` line):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib qt

np.random.seed(19680801)
data = np.random.random((50, 50, 50))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(len(data)):
    ax.cla()
    ax.imshow(data[i])
    ax.set_title("frame {}".format(i))
    # Note that using time.sleep does *not* work here!
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

In **Jupyter**, this works just fine.

In **Spyder** and **IPython** by itself, the animation plays but then the plot window hangs. (This doesn't happen every time, interestingly.) I can then use regular Spyder commands to restart the kernel (I guess matplotlib's new thread has crashed but not the main Python thread).

I tried some other backends. The `inline` backend doesn't have the problem, because it doesn't spawn a new window. Using `TkAgg`, the window closes by itself at the end of execution... I guess this also indicates a crash?

P.S: Using Spyder 4.2.5 and matplotlib 3.3.4.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) There are many issues with plots and old Spyder versions, so you should update to our latest version (5.3.1) if you want to have a good chance of your code to work without hassles.

Comment: Thanks. My upgrade abilities are somewhat limited by Anaconda, but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: To not mess your current installation, please run these commands in the Anaconda Prompt: `conda create -n spyder-env -c conda-forge spyder`, `conda activate spyder`, `spyder`.

Comment: I did basically that. The crash is gone, but I may be having some other issues... I'll make a new post if I can confirm them.

Comment: If you need to use other packages besides what Spyder provides, you need to install them with `conda activate spyder-env` and then `conda install pandas scikit-learn`.